# How can I show log viewer in HTML screen in real time

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, logging

I want to show the contents of a log file which is constantly updating in the back ground in my HTML page in real time. I am using jQuery. Is there any jQuery plugins to do so. I have Websockets but those doesn't work in our existing framework. Please suggest any ideas or links.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX and setInterval.

```
setInterval(function(){
 getlog();
}, 2000);
```

If websockets doesn't exists in your existing framework this is the best.

You can also try out Long Polling with AJAX.
Maybe the answer for this question will help you:
[Simple long polling example with JavaScript and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027005/simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)